# How to catch exceptions from a twisted inlineCallbacks decorated function?

Tags: python, twisted, generator

I am getting started with twisted as one of the libs I'll be using depends on it. In an early test I am confused about how to catch an exception thrown in a function like this:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def read_input_status(self, address, length, callback):
    assert callback
    # ...
```

If `callback`is `None` an `AssertionError` is thrown, so I tried to see it... The function is called like this:

```
def cb():
    pass
def eb():
    pass

d = task.deferLater(reactor, 1, client.read_input_status, 0x0000, 8, None)
d.addCallback(cb)
d.addErrback(eb)
```

I'm calling `deferLater` here on purpose to be able to deal with errors, as I understood that's not possible when using `callLater'. But my errback is never called.

What's weird is that when trying to debug and looking at the twisted lib's code I think I've seen a reason, why my errback is without effect. My decorated generator function (argument `g` below) is called by twisted's `defer._inlineCallbacks` implementation like this (breviated):

```
def _inlineCallbacks(result, g, deferred):
    # ...
    while 1:
        try:
            # ...
            result = g.send(result)
        except:
            deferred.errback()
            return deferred
```

I do see my exception pop up in the last section, where a deferred's errback is then called. But: that is not my deferred... If I go up one call in the debugger's call hierarchy, I see which deferred object is actually passed to `_inlineCallbacks`:

```
def unwindGenerator(*args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
```

Am I mistaken or is this simply a new object, empty, plain, without an callbacks/errbacks attached?

Sorry for this lengthy elaboration. Couldn't find anything immediately related, except for [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407016/testing-with-twisted-and-inlinecallbacks) where I could not directly see how it solves my issue.

Thanks a lot.

[UPDATE] Please see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8080166) for working sample code (Python 2.7.6, Twisted 13.2.0).

Comment: an http://sscce.org/ would be nice.  your code is incomplete, therefore not runnable, therefore not very easily debugged.  the bug may be in some part of your code that you haven't shared in which case the only way anyone can help you is to make an incredibly lucky guess.

Comment: Added gist with sample getting you into the stack trace I am referring to: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8080166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out after rereading the [docs about Twisted Deferred](http://ezyang.com/twisted/defer2.html#auto2) callbacks and errbacks. The issue with the code above and in the linked gist are the missing arguments for callback and errback. If I replace what's written above with the following code, the exception is caught fine and notified via errback as expected:

```
def cb(result):
    pass
def eb(failure):
    pass
```